# Cannot resolve module in sibling directory

Tags: javascript, webpack, node-modules, webpack-5

Good day all!

I am trying to setup a javascript workspace including the posibility to run test script using npm, webpack (and mocha for tests).

So my project structure looks someting like (npm generated files are omitted):

```
root
  |- src
  |    |- main.js
  |    |- MyClass.js
  |- test
  |    |- test.js
  |- package.json
  |- webpack.config.js
```

The `main.js` script is building and debugging fine. But the test script is giving me problems.

In short, I import classes from the project (from the `src` directory) for testing. But it cannot resolve it (eventhough intellisense of vscode is having no issues at all). So if my test-script looked something like:

```js
import { MyClass } from 'MyClass'

/* testing stuff */
```

Intellisense is perfectly capable of resolving the location (as configured in the `jsconfig.json`), but eventhough I set the `src` directory as *include*-rule or as *alias*, webpack is not able to resolve it and tries to search in the `/test` directory instead (and in recursive order all its parent-directories, failing in the same manner).

So the question is how to let webpack resolve for 'nephew' directories?

*(If there is an easier way to use mocha than with the current combined scripts, it would suffice in this case as well. So feedback on that is also welcome, but I defenitly would love to find the answer to the original question)*

Here is the `webpack.config.js` content

```js
const path = require('path');

{
    name: "myProject_test",
    mode: "development",
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./test/test.js"),
    devtool: 'source-map' : '',
    output:
    {
         clean: { dry: true },
         path: path.resolve(__dirname, root, source.outputDir),
         filename: "[id]/[name].js",
    },
    module:
    {
        rules:
        [
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "./test"), path.resolve(__dirname, "./src")],
                exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"), path.resolve(__dirname, "./test/test-dist"), path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules")],
                loader: 'loader-type',
                options: { /* All loader types follow this pattern; so the rest is omited for brevety, but basically this includes all the loaders required for correct compiling */ }
            }
        ],
    },
    resolve:
    {
        alias:
        {
            "*": [path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/*"), path.resolve(__dirname, "./test/*")],
        },
        extensions: ['.json', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss', '.sass', '.html', '.htm']
    },
    devServer:
    {
        contentBase: [path.resolve(__dirname, "./test"), path.resolve(__dirname, "./test/test-dist")],
        /* Other server properties to make this work with server utility */
    }
}
```

And here the `package.json` file content

```js
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "some description",
  "dependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "webpack && mocha test/test-dist --require source-map-support/register --reporter spec --check-leaks --recursive && rm -rf test/test-dist",
    "debug": "webpack serve",
    "start": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": ">=7.x",
    "@babel/preset-env": ">=7.x",
    "babel-loader": ">=8.x",
    "cross-env": ">=7.x",
    "css-loader": ">=6.x",
    "html-loader": ">=2.x",
    "resolve-url-loader": ">=4.x",
    "style-loader": ">=3.x",
    "sass-loader": ">=12.x",
    "sass": ">=1.x",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": ">=2.x",
    "extract-loader": ">=5.x",
    "webpack": ">=5.x",
    "webpack-cli": ">=4.x",
    "webpack-dev-server": ">=3.x",
    "worker-loader": ">=3.x",
    "source-map-support": ">=0.x",
    "mocha": ">=8.x",
    "should": ">=13.x"
  }
}
```